# Camel POJO to PAYLOAD

Tags: java, xpath, soap, apache-camel

I'm handling a web service with camel xml `?dataFormat=POJO` on the `from`

But a front end dev is shoving some data in a field now, and I need to check if it's populated before routing.

But xpath won't work on the SOAP envelope.

```
                <setHeader headerName="hasPdfAlready">
                    <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">
                    //EncodedPdf/text()
                    </xpath>
                </setHeader>

NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value [BlahBlahAPIRequest@0123123123]
```

I need it to be POJO dataformat cause all the other operations expect Soap envelopes.

But now I need to unwrap, in order to test with xpath  (as though I had specified PAYLOAD earlier)

Any idea how to unwrap a soap message, in camel xml dsl, while keeping POJO dataformat?
Thanks

Comment: The body is a `MessageContentsList` that is a **list** . Try to convert the original body (a MessageContentsList) with the first (and unique ?) item of this list (your pojo I guess ?) using `MessageContentsList.get(0)` before invoking xpath

Comment: thanks, I did try that, as per [this ancient answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764627/having-trouble-with-content-based-routing-in-camel-with-a-cxfrs-endpoint-and-xpa?rq=1).  The error changes to BlahBlahAPIRequest can't be converted to org.w3c.dom.Document.  Adding a <convertBodyTo type="org.w3c.dom.Document"> after that didn't work either.  In the end I gave up and made two operations instead of one.